# How to force html title that is changed on the fly to get shown immediately?

Tags: javascript, html, title

What I want to do is like this:when moving cursor to left half part of a div,set it's title to "previous" and when moving to right half part,set it's title to "next".It is easy to do,but question is when cursor enter into right half part first time,hovering for a while,the title got shown then move to left half part,title got set to "previous",but it will never get shown,then move cursor back to right,title won't get shown anymore.I don't want to reload page,how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to change the `title` in jsFiddle (probably because the code runs inside the frame), so I'll post my test page here.

I tried to do exactly what you described and it works fine. The title changes immediately. Tested in Opera, FireFox and Chrome. You may compare it with your code and see what you're doing differently.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Initial title</title>

    <style>
      body, html {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      function foo(event) {
        if (event.pageX * 2 > document.body.clientWidth)
          document.title = 'NEXT';
        else
          document.title = 'PREVIOUS';
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      document.body.onmousemove = foo;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question seems to be about `title` attributes, not `title` element.

Comment: The question is title do changed,but it will not show as tool tip except you move cursor out of element then move in

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want it, as you're a bit scarce on info, such as what element to put the title on (i.e is it a title attribute on a div or something, or just a HTML title element? It's very ambiguous). Also, you don't give us your code so we can't work with that instead.

I wrote this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmbVH/) for a title attribute, as that's what seems more likely. However, I didn't know which element to put it on, so I just used the html() function in jQuery instead. It would be extremely easy to change though.

I'm 100% positive this can be done in less lines of code and less jQuery functions. In fact, it might even be able to be done with CSS3 alone.

Enjoy! :)